# Multiple buttons to control relays

Tags: arduino-mega, button, relay

Dears,

I have a problem that I could not solve for a while, I tried the code below but it did not work.
There will be 4 buttons controlling 4 relays but in a way that button one will turn relays 1&3 on, if button 2 is pressed only relay 2 turns on, if button 3 is pressed relays 1,2 and 3 will turn on, if button 4 is pressed it is supposed to toggle relays 1&4. one more thing: I need to be able to pass from any button to any of the others and the corresponding relays will be activated while the others will go off.

```
    #include <Bounce2.h>

    const int     BUTTON_COUNT = 4;
    const int16_t DEBOUNCE_DELAY = 50;
    const uint8_t buttonPins[BUTTON_COUNT] = {28, 29, 30, 31};
    const uint8_t ledPins[BUTTON_COUNT] = {34, 35, 36, 37};

    Bounce buttons[BUTTON_COUNT];
    uint8_t ledStates[BUTTON_COUNT];

    void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++) {
    buttons[i].attach(buttonPins[i], INPUT);
    buttons[i].interval(DEBOUNCE_DELAY);
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
    ledStates[i] = HIGH;
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], ledStates[i]);
     }
    }

    void loop() {

// Update the debouncers.
for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++)
    buttons[i].update();

// When the first "laban" button is pressed:
if (buttons[0].rose()) {

    // Light up the first LED.
    digitalWrite(ledPins[1], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[3], LOW);

    // and turn off all the others.
    for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++) {
        ledStates[0] = HIGH;
        ledStates[2] = HIGH;
        digitalWrite(ledPins[i], ledStates[i]);
    }
}

// When the first button is released:
if (buttons[0].fell()) {

    // turn off relays.
    digitalWrite(ledPins[1], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[3], HIGH);

}

// When the first "Soda" button is pressed:
if (buttons[1].rose()) {

    // Light up the first LED.
    digitalWrite(ledPins[2], LOW);

    // and turn off all the others.
    for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++) {
        ledStates[0] = HIGH;
        ledStates[1] = HIGH;
        ledStates[3] = HIGH;
        digitalWrite(ledPins[i], ledStates[i]);
    }
}

// When the first button is released:
if (buttons[1].fell()) {

    // turn off the first LED.
   digitalWrite(ledPins[2], HIGH);

}

// When the first "labanUP" button is pressed:
if (buttons[2].rose()) {

    // Light up the first LED.
    digitalWrite(ledPins[1], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[2], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[3], LOW);

    // and turn off all the others.
    for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++) {
        ledStates[0] = HIGH;
        digitalWrite(ledPins[i], ledStates[i]);
    }
}

// When the first button is released:
if (buttons[0].fell()) {

    // turn off the first LED.
     digitalWrite(ledPins[1], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(ledPins[2], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(ledPins[3], HIGH);
}

// When circulation button is pressed:
 if (buttons[3].rose()) {


    // Toggle its state.
    ledStates[3] = !ledStates[3];
    digitalWrite(ledPins[3], ledStates[3]);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[0], ledStates[0]);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is an simple example of what you described, each button will turn on the relays defined for them and turn off other relays. except for button 4 which will toggle relay 1 and 4.

```
int relay1 = 2;
int relay2 = 3;
int relay3 = 4;
int relay4 = 5;
int sw1 = 6;
int sw2 = 7;
int sw3 = 8;
int sw4 = 9;
int sw1Status, sw2Status, sw3Status, sw4Status;
int order = 1; // default is to set all relays off.

void setup() {
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay4, OUTPUT);
  // input pull-up, so default state of buttons is HIGH.
  pinMode(sw1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(sw2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(sw3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(sw4, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  // read the buttons status
  sw1Status = digitalRead(sw1);
  sw2Status = digitalRead(sw2);
  sw3Status = digitalRead(sw3);
  sw4Status = digitalRead(sw4);

  if (sw1Status == LOW) { // if button 1 pressed
    order = 2; // go to case 2
  }
  if (sw2Status == LOW) {
    order = 3;
  }
  if (sw3Status == LOW) {
    order = 4;
  }
  if (sw4Status == LOW) { // button 4 toggle
    if (order != 5) { // if order is not equal 5 turn on relay 1 & 4
      order = 5;
    }
    else { // else go to case 1, which will turns off all relays
      order = 1;
    }
  }

  switch (order) {
    case 1: // if order equals 1
      digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
      break;

    case 2: // if order equals 2
      digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
      break;

    case 3: // if order equals 3
      digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
      break;

    case 4: // if order equals 4
      digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
      break;

    case 5: // if order equals 5
      digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);
      break;

    default: // if none of above cases is valid go to case 1
      order = 1;
      break;
  }
}
```

Having a tidy code format and using simple coding style (if possible) will help to debug/edit/improve the code more easily.

*Don't forget to de-bounce the buttons.*

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately, it did not work the way we were expecting. I thought it maybe my connections so I used the simulator with dc motors instead of the relays and it was the same :(  " 
 https://www.tinkercad.com/things/k1VCQrax95J-copy-of-arduino-simulator-or/editel?tenant=circuits?sharecode=o-fW6ONb4zlq8c6y1JUVCaG0y66HdNzOcTwLNEqftGE=  "

Comment: @medo You shouldn't connect the push buttons to the positive line, we already used the INPUT_PULLUP. remove the resistor and just connect the push button directly to the negative line.

Comment: Highly appreciated @newbie.  What do you think changes need to be made if I replace the push buttons with "TTP 223" touch sensors? any idea of changes on the code? since the sensor has 3 lines; ground, vcc and signal

Comment: @medo well sensors also have high/low output too, in case of using a sensor instead of push button you have to detect sensor status and apply it in the code: `sw1Status, sw2Status ...`. also you should replace `INPUT_PULLUP` with `INPUT`.